# Get TMux scroll buffer contents

Tags: tmux

With TMux, is there any way to programmatically retrieve scroll buffer content from above the current command line?

I'm basically looking to write a bash script to iterate upwards until I find a matching string. To be clear, I don't want to go through history of typed commands; I want to go through everything that appeared on the console.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With *tmux* 1.5 (and later), you can give negative numbers to the `-S` option of `capture-pane` to access the scroll back buffer.

Examples:

- Capture (up to) 32768 lines of the scroll back buffer along with the pane’s current text:

  ```
  tmux capture-pane -pS -32768
  ```
- Capture just the tenth most recently “scrolled off” line:

  ```
  tmux capture-pane -pS -10 -E -10
  ```
- Capture (up to) the 100 most-recently “scrolled off” lines:

  ```
  tmux capture-pane -pS -100 -E -1
  ```
- Capture eleven lines that straddle the current top line of the pane (5 “scrolled off” lines, and the top 6 lines of the pane):

  ```
  tmux capture-pane -pS -5 -E 5
  ```

Note: As with most *tmux* commands, you can use `-t` to target a specific pane if the “current” pane is not the one you are interested in probing.

---

The above examples also use the `-p` option to `capture-pane`, which is only available starting in *tmux* 1.8. With older versions you could work around not having it by using `save-buffer`:

```
tmux capture-pane -S -32768 \; save-buffer - \; delete-buffer
```

Comment: Great, running this against any pane is even better than hoped for.